# AS3 and PHP... saving a screenshot locally and avoiding system dialogs?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, air, dialog, save

After drawing a bitmap of a display object, I need to save the bitmap, as well as text input, locally and avoid system dialogs that flash player would otherwise display while saving out. Can this be achieved with PHP? I've read that Air handles this task pretty effectively, but I'm rather inexperienced with both platforms. Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks...

Comment: Should it also avoid the download dialog? I think at least one user interaction is neccessary to save something localy if you are in a browser. Just for safety reasons.

Comment: Do you need it saved for the user, or would a local SharedObject be sufficient?

Comment: Final output will be a projector app for windows. This is essentially a nice looking photo booth app installed at a museum that takes your photo, puts it in a frame and saves it locally to be sifted thru at a later date.

Comment: This is to say, I have to avoid all system interface at all costs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Allowing webapps to save data on the local system without permission is a HUGE security risk (I could write a legitimate-looking webapp that saves spyware on your system). Flash disallows it for this reason.

Desktop-based (AIR) apps, however, can open a `FileStream` in the `FileMode.WRITE` mode and write data to it without any prompts from the user.

**EDIT**
Since you are looking for a desktop based app, here are a few pointers:

```
var randomname:String=Math.floor(Math.random() * 1024).toString(16) + ".png"
var f:File=File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("photos/" + randomname);
var s:FileStream=new FileStream();
s.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);
s.writeBytes(bytesArray); //bytesArray contains the binary data to write to the file
s.close();
```

Comment: Thank you... It is a dektop based app...AIR it is!

Comment: @MaxG : Next time, you may want to include AIR in your tags as well.

Comment: @kubarium: Next time, you may want to post this comment in the question :)

Comment: Thanks all...will do. This gets me moving in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [FileReference.save()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) for that purpose.
And yes, it requires a user interaction (would be a nightmare otherwise).

This is your only option if you are unwilling to use AIR and [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#methodSummary) class.
AIR file apis don't have that limitation, but require you to run a desktop app.

Well, you can always use local [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) for storing some data, but you will get it AMF-encoded in this case. This will work both with AIR and web apps.

Comment: Thank you... I may have to get tricky. I have to avoid system dialogs at all costs as this is a public install. Not browser based...

Comment: Use File and FileStream classes in AIR app, as I mentioned above. You may easily google for some tutorials on using AIR for reading and saving local files. You'll have what you need: no dialogs and ability to save files almost anywhere on the local file system (with just few limitations).